# Install .NET 4.0 dll to the GAC

Tags: .net, visual-studio, gac, visual-studio-2010

I have a visual C# 2010 express install.  Built a .NET 4.0 dll that is signed.  Now I need to get it into the GAC.  Im on 64bit vista.  Anyone know if there is a gacutil supporting the 4.0 framework yet?  Any other suggestions on getting it into the GAC?

I have tried drag and drop into C:\Windows\assembly, whenever I do, it appears to copy; however, it is not copied and does not produce any error message.

I cannot create a setup/deployment project as it appears the express editions of visual studios do not have the ability.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The GACUtil for .Net Framework 4.0 comes with the Windows SDK v7.0A. I believe this version of the SDK is currently only distributed with the Visual Studio 2010 RC.

**Update:** the latest versjon of the Windows SDK, v7.1, is available for [download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=6b6c21d2-2006-4afa-9702-529fa782d63b&displaylang=en) separate from Visual Studio.

`gacutil.exe` is located in the `\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin` folder.

Comment: Wonderful!!! Thanks!
Link for future searchers: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=4659f71d-4e58-4dcd-b755-127539e21147&displaylang=en